# Extjs 4.2.1 on moveColumn save it's position in grid panel and database

Tags: extjs4.2

I want to move columns in Grid Panel and save its position in database so that next time when i login I will get same column reordering in Grid Panel. I am using following function to move column in gridpanel.

```
columnmove: function (container, coulmn, from, to) {
```

alert('Column Moved From' + from + 'To' + to);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an [`Ext.state.Provider`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.state.Provider):

> Abstract base class for state provider implementations. The provider
>   is responsible for setting values and extracting values to/from the
>   underlying storage source. The storage source can vary and the details
>   should be implemented in a subclass. For example a provider could use
>   a server side database or the browser localstorage where supported.

Alternatively you can use the existing [`Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider) class.

Answer (score 0):

Save the order of the columns in comma separated or some other formats in the database . Next time construct the columns dynamically using the values from the backend.

something like this

```
var selectedColumns = ['Description', 'DateTime', 'Type',  'Status']; 

  var gridColumns = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedColumns.length; i++) {
  var col = {
                    text: selectedColumns[i],                  
                    dataIndex: selectedColumns[i],
                    sortable: true,                  
                    hideable: false,

                };


 gridColumns.push(col);


}

grid.columns= gridColumns
```

or use

```
grid.reconfigure(grid.getStore(), gridColumns);
```